# What controls the default Maven central setting?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I look in IntelliJ's settings under Build -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories, it shows https://jcenter.bintray.com, which I believe has been deprecated.  The help page indicates that this setting comes from the "effective pom".  So I ran `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:effective-pom -Dverbose=true` which shows

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>bintray</name>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>bintray-plugins</name>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Note, there's no line here indicating where that setting comes from.  I checked my `%userprofile%\.m2\settings.xml` and there is no mirror setup. I checked the `apache-maven-3.9.0\conf\settings.xml` and it only had the http blocker mirror.

Where is this setting coming from?  Is it baked in?  Why hasn't it been updated if bintray has sunsetted.

Additionally, if it's sunsetted, why did it work!?

`Downloaded from central: https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/maven-model/3.6.1/maven-model-3.6.1.pom (4.0 kB at 40 kB/s)`

Comment: 1. It probably comes from your parent POM. 2. jcenter probably just redirects to MavenCentral.

Comment: If it had come from the parent POM it should be noted in the effective POM (the dependencies etc are).  I double-checked by looking through the parent and there's no mention.  I do not see any redirections for https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/3.2.0/maven-help-plugin-3.2.0.pom

Answer (score 0):

The Maven -> Repositories configuration is a project-level setting. If it's not defined anywhere in pom.xml or settings.xml of your project, probably there's an old configuration in your .idea folder. Reloading the maven project should update this configuration.

Please also check if there's a jarRepositories.xml under the .idea folder in your project root. Removing the "jcenter" from there might be helpful.

Comment: I want to point out that this value shows under the IDE settings (ctrl+alt+s), not under the project settings (ctrl+alt+shft+s).  However, you are correct - I found this value under `.idea\jarRepositories.xml`.  That, coupled with the fact that the online documentation referencing the effective-pom and providing no way to edit the value is extraordinarily misleading.

Comment: However, it looks like that didn't "solve" the problem.  That value was in the file, but removing it did not remove the value from the settings.  In fact, I deleted the whole `jarRepositories.xml` file and its still there.  I don't know what's controlling it.

Comment: Does it help if you grep "jcenter" in the project folder? Is it possible that it's in your system environment variables?